# Is there a DAO to vote on Ethereum Foundation development decisions / direction?

Tags: decentralization, foundation, dao, voting

I'd like to know if the Ethereum Foundation itself has been decentralized yet.

Is there a DAO with which is used to make decentralized decisions? Is it open to public viewing? Closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "No". The Ethereum foundation have been very public with there plans and activities but it is nevertheless clearly not a DAO.

There are attempts in this direction but nothing concrete yet.